# Will script tags of different type be interpreted as JS?

Tags: html, security, xss

This is more about security than programming, but I'll post it here anyways.

A markup parser renders a **math block** as:

```
<script type="math/tex">

   % tex code here

</script>
```

A client side library (aka MathJax) then detects these `<script>` tags and turns them into math.

My question is: when sanitizing the HTML, is it okay to allow `<script type="tex/math">` tags?
Is there a chance that browsers interpet such a tag as JavaScript (enabling an XSS)?

Comment: Yes. Nope. Browsers will only parse the script tag if it has no type, or the type is JavaScript, either `text/javascript` or `application/javascript`. I wouldn't use anything that ended `/javascript` to be on the safe side, but you're fine with `math/tex`.

Comment: Or `/ecmascript`... `math/tex` is ok though.

Comment: Be careful sanitizing the HTML - this can be a minefield if not done properly. Usually you would encode characters, which means the `<script type="math/tex">` would be encoded as `&lt;script type=&quot;math/tex&quot;&gt;` so my question would be how are you sanitizing the HTML?

Comment: I escape any tag that fails to pass the tests, so yeah, `<script type="math/tex">` would become `&lt;script type=&quot;math/tex&quot;&gt;` if I didn't allow it. Is it safe to keep the tag (and its contents)?

Comment: Clarification: these tags must *not* be escaped, or MathJax won't detect them. But I don't know if I may be introducing a security risk by keeping them unescaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be safe. It depends on *how* you are allowing these tags through whilst HTML encoding everything else.

Also beware of any user controlled content within your script tags.

e.g. if a user could set `% tex code here` to something like

```
</script>
<script>
alert('xssed')
```

then the following would be rendered:

```
<script type="math/tex">

   </script>
   <script>
   alert('xssed')

</script>
```

and then the JavaScript would be executed.

Comment: The user can set `% tex code here` to anything he wants, as long as it doesn't contain any occurences of the string `</script`.